# Managing Memory in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I am doing my project in xcode 4.2 (Older Version). For my application, I just set the variables, arrays in dto class for using in entire app lifecycle. so I set with a property like this.

AppDTO(sub class of NSObject)

AppDTO.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)anotherAppDTO *aAppDTO;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *array1;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *array2;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *string1,*string2,*string3;
```

AppDTO.m

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    self.aAppDTO = [[anotherAppDTO alloc]init];
    self.array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.string1 = @"Hello";
    self.string2= @"Hai";

    }
}


-(void)dealloc
{
    if(array1 != nil)
    {
        [array1 release];
        array1 = nil;
    }

    if(array2 != nil)
    {
        [array2 release];
        array2 = nil;
    }

    [aAppDTO release];
    aAppDTO = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

when I analyze my app in Xcode 4.3.2, I get memory warning in self.array1 and self.array2 (Potential leak on object allocated on line….), but when I change self.array1 to array1, warning goes away.

What is the reason for using self. do I need to use self if I set @property(nonatomic,retain) to variables(like array1,array2,string1,string2).

Also in dealloc method, I heard we don't want to use [self.array1 release], instead we can use [array1 release]. Is it Correct?

Do I need to release my string in dealloc method.

Also I am releasing aAppDTO in dealloc method. if I allocate some objects in anotherAppDTO class, will it release automatically when I call [aAppDTO release] method.

Can anyone clarify me.

Many Thanks,
Anish

Comment: No need to check for `nil` in `dealloc`;  just `release` the objects.   Also, `NSString` properties should pretty much always be `copy` and not `retain`.   If this is a new project, you should be using **ARC**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the warning because when you write :

```
self.array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

is the same as :

```
[self setArray1: [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
```

As you can notice you are not allocating the underlying `array1` private variable, but *you are calling the setter of the property* that since it is declared as **retain** *it retains the object once assigned*, this *means that when you eventually will assign another object the second time with the setter the first object will remain with a retain count of one* until the application will be closed (since you don't have any reference to that object anymore ...) .

Take a look at [this](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/an-in-depth-look-at-manual-memory-management-in-objective-c) great article to understand better Manual Reference Counting in Objective-C .

Comment: oh.. so i don't need to allocate any object if i am using self. Is it same for NSString. here i am using self.string1, will it allocate memory.(like [[NSString alloc]init])

Comment: in the constructor you can simply initialize the private variable, without calling the setter of the property ...

Comment: @Anish i have posted an update to my answer, there is a link to a good article that explains very well how MRC works, take a look ...

Comment: Thanks for the link. i will go through this.

Answer (score 2):

> when i analyze my app in Xcode 4.3.2, i get memory warning in self.array1 and self.array2 (Potential leak on object allocated on line….), but when i change self.array1 to array1, warning goes away.

the analyzer's right. the parameter is `retain`ed when set. as well, you should favor direct access in initialization and `dealloc`. so, you should just write `array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, and be done.

> What is the reason for using self. do i need to use self if i set @property(nonatomic,retain) to variables(like array1,array2,string1,string2).

those go through the accessor methods. if not in initialization or `dealloc`, you should favor going through the accessor methods because that is the common correct execution path for a fully constructed object.

> Also in dealloc method, i heard we don't want to use [self.array1 release], instead we can use [array1 release]. Is it Correct?

correct.

> Do i need to release my string in dealloc method.

yes.

> Also I am releasing aAppDTO in dealloc method. if i allocate some objects in anotherAppDTO class, will it release automatically when i call [aAppDTO release] method.

when its reference count reaches 0, its `dealloc` will be called.

Comment: you have mentioned, i need to release string1 in dealloc method. But for an array, do i need to allocate array in init method, since i am using @property(nonatomic,retain) for an array, it already have an retainCount.

Comment: @Anish the example i gave did *not* use the accessor. that formation transfers the reference to the instance variable (you can then say the `AppDTO` instance holds a reference), which is then relinquished either when the setter is called, or in `dealloc`. as well, objc does not default initialize properties -- initialization simply entails zeroed memory. therefore, the ivar is `nil` when the initializer is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the others have answered your question.

I do want to draw your attention to Apple's excellent [Advance Memory Management Programming Guide: Practical Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html), in which they walk through these sorts of scenarios. It's hard to take it all in on the first reading, but it really does cover this stuff. In answer to your question about the use of instance variables versus the accessor methods, I draw your attention to the section labeled to "Don't Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc".